# Create custom control for a button

Tags: asp.net, button, controls, visible

I want to create a custom control for a button. However wow can i override the visibility of the button?

For example if the access level of the user is `false` then it will hide the button.

Here is my coding

```
 public override void Visible()
   {//Get access right from session
       blcAccessLevel accessLevel = (blcAccessLevel)HttpContext.Current.Session[gbcAccessLevel.sessionAcl];
       if (accessLevel.Read_Access == true)
       {
           base.Visible = true;//error occu
       }
       else
       {
           base.Visible = false;
       }
   }
```

It return me the error.Error **'blcCustomControl.cusAclReadButton.Visible()': cannot override because 'System.Web.UI.Control.Visible' is not a function**   By the way, should I implement the get set method?

Comment: When `Visible` is a property, then *yes*, you need to override it as a property, overriding the setter and getter… (Although this doesn't mean it will work for an ASP.NET control.) So first learn the C# basics.

Comment: I don't know what `Visible()` method you are trying to override. There isn't such a method to override from the base class. Also, post the error you get when you call `this.Visible=true;`

Comment: Hi , i want to override visible of the button, Mayb tje Visible() method is wrong . what method should i nid call?

Comment: @user998405: `Visible` is a property, not a method but I know what you are trying to do. Post the error you get when you call  `base.Visible = true;//error occur`. It's not clear why are you getting an error there and you are not helping yourself too much by not providing the error details.

Comment: @user998405: Look at Rob's answer. That's what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class MyButton : Button
{
    public new bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return (blcAccessLevel)HttpContext.Current.Session[gbcAccessLevel.sessionAcl].ReadAccess;

        }
    }
}
```